# AJAX Form will only either show success message OR post data to database not both

Tags: ajax, forms, codeigniter, controller

I am using Codeigniter as my framework and have a simple contact form. This uses the form helper and i have used AJAX and a fallback in the controller if AJAX is not present.

At the moment, my code with only either show the success message from the ajax form OR post the data to the database depending on if i change them around in the controller - my error messages work fine.

I am confused to how it will not both post and show success message - i think i may be missing something in my controller or AJAX request?

Here is my code as a guidance and if anyone can spot anything that would be great as it's getting on my nerves now!

*The code i am posting now lets the data be posted into the database. When i move the post data elements below this -> `return $this->output->set_output(json_encode($respond)); It doesn't post to the database but shows the success message and vice versa.`

CONTROLLER,

```
// if ajax request
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {   
            $respond = array();
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $respond['result'] = 'false';

                $respond['error_message'] = $error_message;
                $respond['errors'] = validation_errors();

                // set individual errors - for warning classes
                $respond['first_name_error'] = form_error('first_name');
                $respond['country_error'] = form_error('country');
                $respond['email_error'] = form_error('email');
                $respond['message_error'] = form_error('message');

            } else {

                $respond['result'] = 'true';
                $respond['success_message'] = $success_message; 

                // add contact message to the database
                $this->contact_model->insert_contact_message($curr_lang, $this->input->post('first_name'), $this->input->post('country'), $this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('phone'), $this->input->post('message'));
            }
            return $this->output->set_output(json_encode($respond));

        } else {
            // if ajax request failed - use CI
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                $data['error_message'] =  $error_message;
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
            } else {
                // add contact message to the database
                $this->contact_model->insert_contact_message($curr_lang, $this->input->post('first_name'), $this->input->post('country'), $this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('phone'), $this->input->post('message'));

                $data['success_message'] = $success_message;

            }
        }

        // set field labels
        $data['first_name'] = $first_name;
        $data['country'] = $country;
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['phone'] = $phone;
        $data['message'] = $message;

        // initialize view name
        $data['content'] = $page;

        // load the view
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
```

AJAX

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // send the form data to the controller
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(respond) {
                if(respond.result === 'false'){
                    // function to add warning class
                    function add_error(response, field){
                        if(response){
                            $(field).addClass('warning');
                        }
                    }

                    // add warning classes - doing this individually as some inputs have more than one error message
                    add_error(respond.first_name_error, 'input[name="first_name"]');
                    add_error(respond.country_error, 'input[name="country"]');
                    add_error(respond.email_error, 'input[name="email"]');
                    add_error(respond.message_error, 'textarea');

                    // post all errors to the view
                    var error_msg = respond.error_message + respond.errors;
                    $('#error_message').html(error_msg);    

                }
                if(respond.result === 'true'){
                    // empty the form
                    $('#error_message').empty();
                    $('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val('');

                    // set the success message
                    var success_msg = respond.success_message;
                    $('#success_message').html(success_msg).fadeOut(6000);                  
                }
            }     
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you aren't parsing the JSON response so your if statements will never be true (as respond.result is probably evaluating to 'undefined').

Comment: So how exactly would i parse the JSON else statement? sorry if this is simple but new applying AJAX.

Comment: you could try something like var respond = JSON.parse(respond);

Comment: Unfortunately no, comes back with errors saying SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character in firebug hmmm

Comment: If you change respond.result === 'false' or respond.result === 'true' to respond.result === 'undefined', does the success callback fire?

Comment: When i change false to undefined, no error messages or success messages appear. When i change true to undefined, error messages work and success still doesn't and on both time the data is posted to the database, confusing! ---If it helps that when i do this: if(respond.result === 'true'){ alert('hello'); I still dont get an alert but when i remove the post data section in my controller i get the alert and the success message fades in but obv's no data is posted to the db

Comment: What is alerted when you do this:

    success: function(respond) { alert(respond.result);
        if(respond.result === 'false'){ ... ?

Comment: When i alert the respond.result before the false i get an alert of false. I realised as well that if i leave a field blank and get my error message for it, type something in and submit, it submits but error message still doesnt go, i assume its due to this problem as well

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax respond.result === true or false not 'true' or 'false'. You just need to remove the quotes because it is a Boolean not a string.